# Beep patterns generator

Tags: digital-logic, driver, piezo-buzzer

I would like to generate the following beep patterns using a `piezo buzzer`:

1. Single long beep
2. Two short beeps
3. Single short beep

Is there any specific chip I can use for it. Any simple automatic circuit which can do this is highly welcomed.

Comment: I noticed you've asked a few AVR questions before, using an ATtiny would probably be the simplest circuit. Other ways I can think of would involve a couple of chips.

Comment: Your specs don't mention what triggers a specific pattern (or is it justy one pattern of 4 short beeps? how about the silences??) Anyway, with a small micro-controller the *circuit* will be very simple...

Comment: @PeterJ: I understand that it's easily possible with microcontroller. I wanted a simpler approach. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: For instance, one pulse on a pin generates first one, on a second pin second pattern, and so on

Comment: 'for instance' is not a sign of a solid specification.... And in what sense do you want it simpeler than one 8-pin chip (plus maybe a transistor buffer)? (6 pin if you consider a PIC10F200)?

Comment: You can do it even by one capacitor + 3 resistor + transistor! also by a simple and tiny MCU, too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest circuit is a small microcontroller.  Generating a beep is as simple as putting out a square wave.  Many micros have PWM generators built in, which can automate this.  However, your application is so simple that explicit code can emit the beeps once you decide how long the on and off parts will be.

Even a PIC 10F200 can do this, since you only need 4 I/O lines.  The main loop waits for one of the input lines to be asserted, loads up the counters for numbers of beeps and beep duration accordingly, jumps to the code that does the beeping, waits for all lines to be unasserted, and does it all again.